# How to count lengths of contents of an array of pointers

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to count the length of the contents of an array of pointers: 
For example
`char *str[MAX] = {"kendrick", "lamar"};`. the length of `str[0]` is 8 and `str[1]` is 5. Is there a way of getting these values.

Comment: What do you mean 'lengths of contents'? The string with max size? min size? Average size? Or maybe the sum of the lengths?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: In general, no.  If guaranteed NUL-terminated C-'strings' or the 'real' C++ string type, then possibly..

Comment: The sticking point, even with strings whose length can be determined, is the length of the pointer array, ie. the number of valid entries in it.  [MAX] does not suggest that length is fully defined in the question:(

Answer (score 2):

You can verify if each pointer is NULL or not:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    if(str[i] != NULL)
        count++;

printf("Count: %d\n", count);
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, it is not clear what you are exactly asking about.

In a hurry, I wrote the following code to give multiple outputs so you may find what you are looking for:

1- Length of each item by using [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) function.(`ilength`)
2- Total length of the items by adding up individual lengths. (`ilength`).
3- Number of items in the array by counting non `NULL` (`items`).

```
int main()
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    char* str[MAX] = {"Hello", " World","!",""};

    int ilength, length = 0, items = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        if (str[i] != NULL)
        {   ilength = strlen (str[i]);
            // WARNING!!! ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'
            cout << i << " item length is " << ilength << "\n";
            length = length + ilength;
            items += 1;
        }

    cout << "\nTotal length of all items is: " << length << "\n\n";
    cout << "\nThere is/are " << items << " in the array.\n\n";
}
```

---

NOTE: If you use C++ compiler, pay attention to the warning:

`WARNING!!! ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'`

Comment: there is no C++/C language. Decide which one

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Why you say so? I did not get your point. would you please explain as I do not have much knowledge of C.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the strings are all null-terminated, you can use [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: ...but that doesn't tell how many entries the array has (which I believe is the question).

Comment: Oh. Then you want to loop over the range [0, MAX) and count the non-null entries in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing as it is not clear what length you want. Therefore for both possibilities:

1. Length of array in use:

`char *str[MAX] = {"kendrick", "lamar"};` is an array of size MAX with two entries, which are pointers to strings. The compiler will initialize all other entries to zero, so counting how many entries of `str` are non-zero will give you that answer.

2. Length of the strings:

A string in C is null terminated. So for each entry of `str` that is not null you can advance and advance until you encounter a null character. That tells you the length of that entry.

Comment: Made a mistake on the `MAX`. its not supposed to be their.